# Matching contents of two files with each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that presents the amount of viewers each channel has had during one day, and what shows have been the most popular. I have two files, one that shows the measurements (http://www.csc.kth.se/~vahid/DD1310/P/tittardata.txt) where the first numbers are the time stamps, and the number after the slash is the channel. The other file (http://www.csc.kth.se/~vahid/DD1310/P/program.txt) shows the content that each channel has on that day. 
What I am trying to figure out now is how to best match the time stamps from the first file with the correct title from the second file. Thus far I have created a dictionary that holds the title as key and the corresponding time stamps as values. 
For example 
I have

```
{"Aktuellt" : [21.07/1, 21.22/1]}
```

I have also created a list from the first file that counts the amount of times one time stamp occurs, when the list is printed it looks like this

```
[['19.37/2', 34], ['19.52/2', 34], ['21.07/1', 57], ['21.22/1', 48], ...
```

What I would like to do is match the time stamps with the correct title, so that the list instead would be

```
['Aktuellt', 57], ['Aktuellt', 48]
```

Is that possible, or should I do something else to be able to present a "top 10 shows"

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Note that if this were an actual problem you will need to clarify what the timestamps mean and if the number of timestamps recorded truly represent the number of `viewer-hours / program-hours` of the shows (a measure of their popularity). As for counting the number of timestamps while they were airing, you will need to convert the timestamps into an `{ hour: int, minute: int, channel: int}` kind of structure in order to do less/greater-than comparisons with the air times. Finally, refrain from asking hw questions on SO, as they are not generally useful.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the time stamps as keys and the titles as value:

```
initial_dict = {"Aktuellt" : [21.07/1, 21.22/1]}
d = {e : k for k, v in initial_dict.items() for e in v}
# d = {'21.07/1' : "Aktuellt", '21.22/1': "Aktuellt"}

l = [['19.37/2', 34], ['19.52/2', 34], ['21.07/1', 57], ['21.22/1', 48]]


[[d[f], s] for f, s in l if f in d]
```

output:

```
[['Aktuellt', 57], ['Aktuellt', 48]]
```

if you want to get the top 10 you can do:

```
top_10 = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1])[-10:]
top_10_with_title =  [[d[f], s] for f, s in first_10 if f in d]
```

Comment: Cool! I will try that... Is there a way to reverse the keys and values since the values right now are in an array?

Comment: why do you want to reverse?

Comment: @bella98 your want to get from `{"Aktuellt" : [21.07/1, 21.22/1]}` to `{'21.07/1' : "Aktuellt", '21.22/1': "Aktuellt"}` ?

Comment: exactly! since it's a very long dict I'm just wondering if I need to do it manually

Comment: it doesn't seem to work on my dicts and lists since I have made them directly from the files and not written them in the code

Comment: you have more than 1 dict ? and 1 list?